# Mongo query group by and output only subtotal great than 1

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to group by user and email and only output the subtotal > 1. I tried this but it is failed to compile.

```
db.member.aggregate( 
{"$group" :  {
   _id : {user:"$user", email: "$email"}, 
   count : { $sum : { if: { $gte: [ "$sum", 1 ] }, then: 1, else: 0 } 
} } } )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to try and fit everything into a single [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage. It's an aggregation "pipeline" and should be used as such. Just at a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) at the end:

```js
db.member.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "user": "$user", "email": "$email" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gte": 1 } } }
])
```

It's basically required anyway, since "first" you accumulate, and then you filter. Much like `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` in SQL.

Also see [SQL To Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the core documentation for common examples.